# AfO Cast from Direct Variable to Characteristic Member Variable

Tags: hana

I have HANA Database where I have my data stored in tables. Using HAna DB studio y create Calculation views. These views are then consumed by the user through the excel plug in Analysis for Office.

One of my users gets the following error when trying to load the query:

[image: Error Message]

It is in German, but essentially it says an object from type "INADirectVariable" cannot be transformed into type "INACharacteristicMemberVariable".

I have no idea what these types are and have not been able to find any literature regarding the topic.

I would really appreciate it if someone could shed some light on this topic.

Thanks